# Trouble integrating jquery/ajax into django project

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am relatively new to coding and am having problems getting jquery/ajax to work in my django/bootstrap project. At the start of my header I have included the following code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

However, when trying to run a simple function:

```
<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint='/api/data/'

$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})


{% endblock %}
```

I keep getting the same two errors displayed in the console:

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $.ajax is not a function TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8002/chart/:87:7)
at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js:2:29453)
at t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js:2:29755) undefined

Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):87)
at e (jquery.min.js:2)
at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Most answers that I have seen here seem to revolve around installing the slim version of jQuery that does not include Ajax. However, I believe that this is not the case here.

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Turns out that when adding bootstrap (which I did a long time ago), jQuery is imported (which was put in my footer). This overwrote my regular version of jQuery with the slim version.